# how to use services in angularjs to share data across multiple controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, controllers

I want to share data across multiple controllers in angularjs without using $rootScope. I am learning to use services for the same. What is wrong with the following code?

This is my controllers.js :

```
function Ctrl1(shareData) {
  shareData.setValue("my_data");
}

function Ctrl2($scope, shareData) {
  $scope.value = shareData.getvalue();
}
```

This is my services.js :

```
angular.module('connectionsServices').
  factory('shareData', function() {
  var shareVar = 'undefined';
    return {
              getValue: function() {
          return shareVar;
          },

              setValue: function(value) {
          shareVar = value;
          }
       }
       });
```

But it is not working.

Comment: If you have Fiddle or Plunker will help a lot to play with

Comment: You have a typo. In Ctrl2, `shareData.getvalue();` should be `shareData.getValue();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind service variable to controller variable, your code is changing `shareVar` but you are unable to see it, you can update the view like this:

HTML:

> ```
> <div ng-app="testApp">
>     <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">{{ value }}
>         <br />
>         <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
>             <button type="button" ng-click="change(); update();">Change me!</button>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

JS:

```
angular.module('testApp', []).factory('shareData', function ($window) {
    var shareVar = 'undefined';
    return {
        getValue: function () {
            return shareVar;
        },

        setValue: function (value) {
            shareVar = value;
        }
    };
});

function Ctrl1($scope, $window, shareData) {
        $scope.change = function () {
            shareData.setValue("my_data");
        };
    }

    function Ctrl2($scope, shareData) {
        $scope.value = shareData.getValue();

        $scope.update = function () {
            $scope.value = shareData.getValue();
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Services provide an easy way for us to share data and functionality
>   throughout our app. The services we create are singletons that can be
>   injected into controllers and other services, making them the ideal
>   place for writing reusable code.

Follow its link https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services